# Installing Ubuntu with Windows 8 goes dark

Tags: installation, dual-boot

I'm a little new to Ubuntu. Though I used Ubuntu before but not too much. I'm running windows 8. On my Desktop. Its a little old actually. The CPU is Pentium D with 1.5GB RAM. But I don't think that's a problem for Ubuntu 13.04. 
I used Ubuntu 12.04 besides Win7. But this time I'm unable to install Ubuntu. Actually there is no error. I've tried. Install ubuntu,  try ubuntu without installing and the installation helper. But the same thing happens each time. I can reach the boot screen(ubuntu logo and fits under it) and than the monitor goes offline. Though the CPU fan,  mouse and the keyboard is online but no response.

I've downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 from the official site and burned it in a DVD. I tried burning two different DVDs. Considering if there is any error with that.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine does this EXACT thing! Are you using an SSD by any chance? I really want to know what's causing this. If I had more rep, I'd certainly put a bounty on this.

Comment: Add your graphic card details to the question.

Comment: I'm using WD blue 512GB HDD.
NVDIA GFORCE 9400GT

Comment: Someone told me that it's the RAM(1.5GB) But Windows8 is dealing fine with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentium D are quite old but still working with Linux. Your memory base is not a problem, nor the disk.

Graphic card is not a problem too since Nvidia cards are well supported.

You have to try first the "Live" session by downloading the Raring Tail 32 bit version of Lubuntu. Lubuntu is the light-most version of Ubuntu distribution. It uses LXDE desktop environment very light but complete and fast.

If the "Live" session will work well for you, you can eventually decide to install it permanently on your disk.

This is the link to the 32 bit iso:
http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/raring/release/lubuntu-13.04-desktop-i386.iso

Further useful links:
http://lubuntu.net/
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall

Let we know what you will experience so the community will improve, possibly, the support.

Comment: Thanks man for the help. I didn't have to go for Lubuntu. Ubuntu 12.04 Installed fine.

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if the kernel does not load the correct graphics driver. Try passing nomodeset kernel bootparameter and see if it works.

Comment: If you don't mind telling me how to do that. 
I don't have much experience about Ubuntu and matters related to this as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

When you see Grub, press "E", then you can edit the boot parameters. But I would also recommend to try boot into safe mode and see if it works.